# R-missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed when using is.na

Tags: r

I have a code like that in R

```
for (index in c(1:nrow(my_data) - 2)){
  if (!is.na(my_data[index, 1]) && !is.na(my_data[index + 1, 1]) && !is.na(my_data[index + 2, 1])) {
    print("yes")
  }
}
```

but I have the error

```
Error in if (!is.na(my_data[index, 1]) && !is.na(my_data[index + 1, 1]) &&  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` operator takes precedence over the `-` operator, so the code  `c(1:nrow(my_data) - 2)` doesn't do what you think it does. Suppose `my_data` is a data frame with 10 rows. Then your code is the same as `c(1:10 - 2)`

This is **not** the same as `1:8`. It is the same as taking 2 away from each member of the set `1:10`. Your indexing therefore starts at -1, which of course is not defined, and causes your error.

Answer (score -1):

Put `nrow(my_data)-2` inside brackets.

This should work

```
for (index in c(1:(nrow(my_data) - 2))){
  if (!is.na(my_data[index, 1]) && !is.na(my_data[index + 1, 1]) && !is.na(my_data[index + 2, 1])) {
    print("yes")
  }
}
```